# How to add tailwind to a .less file

Tags: less, tailwind-css

I have a gatsby project that uses `.less` as the CSS preprocessor, adding tailwind to it as shown in the docs does nothing

```
@tailwind base
@tailwind utilities
@tailwind components
```

How can I add tailwind to a `.less` file ?

Answer (score 3):

in less can import tailwind as css files you can try it

```
@import "~tailwindcss/base.css";
@import "~tailwindcss/components.css";
@import "~tailwindcss/utilities.css";
```

Comment: Thanks, Tailwind's generation using '@tailwind' instead of '@import' (the correct one) even my styles is .less, they should enhance it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tailwind with react, add

```
@tailwind base
@tailwind utilities
@tailwind components
```

to `./src/index.css` file

refer: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app